# Unable to stop repeating the div calling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created one warning msg for warning the incorrect phone number. it is displaying even if the warning message is displayed. I want to check whether the error msg is displayed if no then display else dont want to display .
Here is my code.
jquery code

```
$('#mobile').val().length != 10
        ? (
            $('#errorID')
                ?
                $("#mobile").after('<div id="errorID" class="alert alert-danger">Please enter Valid mobile</div>')
                : null
        )
         : 
         ($("div").remove("#errorID"), mob = ($("#mobile").val()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`.length`**

- `$('#errorID').length > 0` there is a div *even without `> 0` it will return true as well*
- `$('#errorID').length < 1` there is no div
- While id should be unique you can directly use `$("#errorID").remove()`